# Usages of Constants in Constructor

Tags: scala

It´s most probably a stupid question, I saw an answer already here but seems does not work in my particular case. Here my code

```
object ProductAdded{
  val PRODUCT_NAME:String="productName"
  val PRODUCT_PRICE:String="productPrice"
}

class ProductAdded @JsonCreator()(@JsonProperty(PRODUCT_NAME) var productName: String,
                                  @JsonProperty(PRODUCT_PRICE) var productPrice: String) extends Event {


  @JsonProperty(PRODUCT_NAME) def getProductName: String = {
    productName
  }

  @JsonProperty(PRODUCT_PRICE) def getProductPrice: String = {
    productPrice
  }
}
```

I´m trying to use those constants in the constructor, but when I compile show this error

```
Error:(12, 49) annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: event.ProductAdded.PRODUCT_NAME
class ProductAdded @JsonCreator()(@JsonProperty(PRODUCT_NAME) var productName: String,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty unfortunate error message, I must say, since Scala doesn't actually have a concept named "constant", so how are you supposed to make something a "constant" if you don't even know what it is?

Scala *does*, however, have a concept of "[constant expression](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#constant-expressions)" (**bold** emphasis mine):

> ## 6.24 Constant Expressions
>
> Constant expressions are expressions that the Scala compiler can evaluate to a constant. The definition of "constant expression" depends on the platform, but they include at least the expressions of the following forms:
>
> - A literal of a value class, such as an integer
> - A string literal
> - A class constructed with `Predef.classOf`
> - An element of an enumeration from the underlying platform
> - A literal array, of the form Array(c<sub>1</sub>, …, c<sub>n</sub>), where all of the c<sub>i</sub>'s are themselves *constant expressions*
> - **An identifier defined by a *constant value definition***.

and "[constant value definition](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions)" (**bold** emphasis mine):

> A *constant value definition* is of the form
>
> ```
> final val x = e
> ```
>
> where `e` is a *constant expression*. **The `final` modifier must be present and no type annotation may be given**.

So, as you can see, your expression is not a *constant value expression*, because the definition is not a *constant value definition*.

In order to turn it into a *constant value definition*, you need to

- remove the type annotation `: String`
- add the `final` modifier *explicitly*: even though members of a singleton `object` are *implicitly* `final`, *constant value definition*s require an *explicit* annotation

The result would look something like this:

```
object ProductAdded {
  final val PRODUCT_NAME  = "productName"
  final val PRODUCT_PRICE = "productPrice"
}

class ProductAdded @JsonCreator()(
  @JsonProperty(PRODUCT_NAME)  var productName:  String,
  @JsonProperty(PRODUCT_PRICE) var productPrice: String
) extends Event {
  @JsonProperty(PRODUCT_NAME)  def getProductName  = productName
  @JsonProperty(PRODUCT_PRICE) def getProductPrice = productPrice
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Still seems weird see a final val when val is final by definition.

Comment: Well, it makes the rules for constant value definitions much simpler. You can see at a glance whether or not a `val` is a constant value definition. Otherwise you would first have to check "Is this within an `object`? Okay, then it is implicitly `final` because you can't inherit from an `object`. But if it is within a `class` or a `trait`, then it is only `final` if it is *explicitly* annotated, and if it *isn't* `final` then it can be overridden and is thus not constant." It's much easier just to say: "well, is there a `final` keyword in front of it? Yes, good, then it's constant."

Comment: I understand is a shortcut for the compiler, but make the code weird to read. Anyway at least is white magic, now that I understand why it's needed. Thanks again mate!

Comment: It is *not* a shortcut for the compiler. The compiler knows full well that `val`s in an `object` are `final` and `val`s in a `class` or `trait` are *not*. And that for that reason, `val`s in an `object` are *always* constant, whereas `val`s in a `trait` or `class` are *only* constant when they are *explicitly* annotated as `final`. After all, it needs to know that information *anyway* to determine if you are allowed to override a `val` or not, plus that information does not only apply to `val`s but also to `def`s, and needs to be known for that reason also. The rule is for *you*, the *human*.

Comment: It is simply easier to just look "is there a `final` keyword, okay, then it's constant" than to remember all the rules when a `val` can be overridden and when not. (Hint: `val`s can pretty much always be overridden, except in `object`s, for the simple reason that `object`s cannot be inherited from *at all*.)

Comment: cool, you´re right, I completely forgot about inheritance. The fact that was inside an object confuse me.